# Windows Licensing Monitoring Service (WLMS) has stopped. Upgraded 2008 R2 from Eval ISO

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012

Upgrade path: 2008 -> 2008 R2 (using Eval ISO) -> 2012 R2 (using retail disk)
I currently have Windows 2012 R2 installed.  I've upgraded the 2008 to 2008 R2 using a eval iso from Microsoft.  Then upgrade it to 2012 R2 using my retail copy.  Now i get a message saying that WLMS has stopped and it can't be started.  I've check to make sure that the OS is not an eval.  I suspect that the serviced got carried over from the 2008 R2 eval installation.  Is there away to get rid of this service?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the solution with editing the Registry as it is suggested below:

1> Run regedit using elevated privileges.

2> Navigate to HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WLMS.

3> Right click on WLMS and select Permissions.

4> Click Advanced button and select Owner Tab.

5> Change owner to Administrators, click Replace owner... and press Apply.

6> Click OK and on the Security tab, make sure that Administrators have Full Control. Click OK.

7> Change the Start value for the WLMS service to 4.

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/77d68d0d-be7e-4721-85d0-9db8fffa3568/disable-wlms-windows-license-monitoring-service?forum=winserversetup

Answer (score 2):

- Open Task Scheduler
- Create new Task
- User account: SYSTEM
- Run with highest privileges
- Actions => New... => Start a program
- Program/script: C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe
- Arguments: add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WLMS /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 4 /f

Start once or trigger.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have enough rep to comment.

I needed to stop the WLMS service on a 2016 server. Danny's answer ended ended up being the one that worked for me. batistuta09's answer wouldn't allow me to save changes.

I used this PS command to create the task, execute it in 10 seconds then set the task to be deleted once it expires.

```
$t = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (get-date).AddSeconds(10); $t.EndBoundary = (get-date).AddSeconds(60).ToString('s'); Register-ScheduledTask -Force -TaskName DisableWLMS -Action (New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe" -Argument 'add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WLMS /v Start /t REG_DWORD /d 4 /f') -Trigger $t -User "SYSTEM" -Settings (New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -DeleteExpiredTaskAfter 00:00:01)
```